# QRCode application with customization

Tags: java, qr-code

I am working with QRCode api found [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/)

I successfully implemented the QRCode generation through Api but the result is this

[image]

*(I changed the color from White to yellow in order to ask my question)*

So, now if you see you find that the outer boundary is very thick I want it to be thin..like this

[image]

The code I used to generate the qrcode and changing the color is this

```
public boolean writeImage(String qrMessageForGeneratingQRCode,String filename){

    boolean result = false;

    try{
        int length = 200;
        int breadth = 200;
        BufferedImage originalQRCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(QRCode.from(qrMessageForGeneratingQRCode).withSize(length,breadth).stream().toByteArray()));
        BufferedImage changedQRCodeBufferedImage = new ColorChanger().changeColor(originalQRCodeBufferedImage, Color.WHITE, new Color(255,202,0));
        ImageIO.write(changedQRCodeBufferedImage,FilesUtil.getProperty("QR_CODE_IMAGE_FORMAT") , new File(filename));
        result = true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please shed some light how can I achieve that using code....Thanks in advance....
Ankur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quiet zone around the QR code needs to be 4 modules. You don't want to reduce this. Your proposed image will be harder to scan.

You can always edit the BufferedImage after the fact with a simple crop:

```
BufferedImage crop = original.getSubimage(50, 50, original.getWidth() - 2*50, original.getHeight() - 2*50);
```

BTW you should update the underlying zxing library used in your solution to at least 2.0, probably 2.1-SNAPSHOT. 1.7 is old.

Comment: Whats the meaning of 4 modules..is it the length of thickness...?

Comment: Four times the width of one square unit in the QR code. The original image looks like it has that minimum margin.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer would be to reduce the `length` and `breadth` values. Did you try that?

Comment: Obviously i tried that, but the ratio gets shortened....that was the first step I tried....
:)